# how can I avoid the 'selected' state of a button remaining when the action is abandoned by pressing the Cancel button in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I have a code with some buttons and some associated OK/Cancel dialog on each. The overall code does properly what it should, but there is a visual glitch that I don't know how to avoid/handle: the hovering 'select' status of a button continue to remain selected after hitting its Cancel button action.

In order to exemplify, I made a stripped down test code of my real one, shown below, that mimics somewhat the original program structure (which also has toolbar, status bar etc.).

Just run the code and follow the hint displayed on the right pane. The text on the warning dialog is just a dumb text made only for this test.

Question: how to restore tyhe original button color after hitting the Cancel button? (except with the mouse over hovering)

Edit: this is on Windows OS.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((438, 300))
        self.SetTitle("frame")
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.window_1 = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.window_1.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)
        sizer_1.Add(self.window_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.window_1_pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self.window_1_pane_1, wx.ID_ANY, "button_1")
        self.button_1.SetMinSize((75, 75))
        self.button_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x66, 0x77, 0x88))
        self.button_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)

        self.button_2 = wx.Button(self.window_1_pane_1, wx.ID_ANY, "button_2")
        self.button_2.SetMinSize((75, 75))
        self.button_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x66, 0x77, 0x88))
        self.button_2.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc))
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)

        self.window_1_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_3.Add(sizer_4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self.window_1_pane_2, wx.ID_ANY,
            "Change focus to the button below with the Tab key on keyboard, "\
            "then click one of the buttons on the left and then hit Cancel.\n"\
            "To restore the buttons's 'selected' status, just hover the mouse over it.",
            style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4.Add(label_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.button_3 = wx.Button(self.window_1_pane_2, wx.ID_ANY, "reset color")
        sizer_4.Add(self.button_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.window_1_pane_2.SetSizer(sizer_3)
        self.window_1_pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.window_1.SplitVertically(self.window_1_pane_1, self.window_1_pane_2)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

        self.button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.change_button_1)
        self.button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.change_button_2)
        self.button_3.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.reset_color)

    def change_button_1(self, event):
        self.dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None,
        "CAUTION\n\nYou are about to chage button 1 color!",
        "Color change warning", wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_WARNING)
        self.dlg_result = self.dlg.ShowModal()
        self.dlg.Destroy()

        if self.dlg_result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.button_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0xcc, 0x32, 0x32))
            self.button_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x66, 0x77, 0x88))

    def change_button_2(self, event):
        self.dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None,
        "CAUTION\n\nYou are about to chage button 2 color!",
        "Color change warning", wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_WARNING)
        self.dlg_result = self.dlg.ShowModal()
        self.dlg.Destroy()

        if self.dlg_result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.button_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0xcc, 0x32, 0x32))
            self.button_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x66, 0x77, 0x88))

    def reset_color(self, event):
        self.button_2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x66, 0x77, 0x88))
        self.button_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0x66, 0x77, 0x88))

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried with wxPython 4.1 on Python 3.6 and things seem to work as expected.

So, your problem could be a version specific bug.

What versions are you using?

Did you try to call `self.button_2.Refresh()`?
You could also try to call `event.Skip()` in your event handler.

Comment: I am using wx.version \'4.2.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.2.2.1\' and Python 3.11.3. The `self.button_2.Refresh()` method solved the issue. Thank you :)